# Need help with the syntax

Tags: trigger

How to change ownerId of an existing document to 'System Admin' Profile, I tried doing this,

```
if(a.Doc_Status__C == 'Duplicate'){  
update ownerid = '00554540w5rr';  
}
```

00554540w5rr is the Id for System admin. I want to use ProfileName ('system admin') instead of OwnerId
Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *moved to X profile*? That doesn't mean anything to me. Can you [edit] your post to be more clear?

Comment: Are you attempting to change the owner of the record to a queue? You cannot change the owner of a record to a profile.

Comment: If you want to change the owner to a user that has the System Admin profile, then you would need to query for that user, eg: `Id sysAdminID = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'system admin' LIMIT 1 ].Id;` and then use `a.ownerid = sysAdminID;` to assign it.  Your `update` should be `update a;` on a separate line, probably outside the if block. The problem, though, is that this will get a user who has that profile, but many users can have the same profile. Without additional information, you can't guarantee that the same user would be made the new owner each time.

Answer (score 1):

From the ID you are trying to give, it seems to be a User ID (starting with 005). You could assign owner as User/Queue, but not profile.

Just update as follows:

```
if(a.Doc_Status__C == 'Duplicate'){  
    a.ownerid = '00554540w5rr';
    update a;
}
```

Update Syntax:

```
Update [sObject OR list<sObject>]
```